# Getting the error while creating spark context py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I am trying to create spark context object with the following commands on pyspark:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('App_name').setMaster("spark://local-or-remote-ip:7077").set('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'cassandra-machine-ip').set('spark.storage.memoryFraction', '0.2').set('spark.rdd.compress', 'true').set('spark.streaming.blockInterval', 500).set('spark.serializer', 'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer').set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR').set('spark.mesos.coarse', 'true')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/spark-1.4.1/python/pyspark/conf.py", line 106, in __init__
  self._jconf = _jvm.SparkConf(loadDefaults)
File "/usr/local/lib/spark-1.4.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 766, in __getattr__
File "/usr/local/lib/spark-1.4.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 362, in send_command
File "/usr/local/lib/spark-1.4.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 318, in _get_connection
File "/usr/local/lib/spark-1.4.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 325, in _create_connection
File "/usr/local/lib/spark-1.4.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 432, in start
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server
```

I have built spark jar using sbt and when when I ran it through scala I got this error:

```
ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18,5,main] org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up
```

Though master is working.

Comment: I am using mesos configuration. But I don't think that there is any issue with it as I am getting the same error executing the command :

    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("App_name").setMaster("spark://127.0.0.1:7077")

Comment: OK, you don't give us much to go on here. For starters how did you deploy the Spark. Does it in local mode? Does it work when you use native code (Scala for example). And why mesos here? Do you use Mesos cluster or standalone?

Comment: I have built spark jar using sbt and when when I ran it through scala I got this error:

ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18,5,main]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.

Comment: I executed it through pyspark shell and spark-shell

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35862915/edit) the question to include this details.

Comment: updated the question.